# knockout.jsでko.utils.arrayFilter() methodを使いたい

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

文字列のリストがあり、inputボックスからタイプして検索をかけると、リストと照会してフィルターされるという機能のサイトがあります。
knockout.jsを使ってシンプルにできた例を見つけたのですが、これにko.utils.arrayFilter() methodを使って同じ機能にしたいです。

https://codepen.io/crkuplich/pen/VWgjXV

```js
// Model
var locations = [
  { name: 'My House' },
  { name: 'Bakery' },
  { name: 'Restaurant' },
  { name: 'Supermarket' },
  { name: 'Pub' }
];

// ViewModel
var ViewModel = function(locations) {
  var self = this;

  self.locations = locations;
  self.filter = ko.observable('');
  // filteredLocations is computed based on the filter observable
  // entered by the user
  this.filteredLocations = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.locations.filter(function(location) {
      return location.name.indexOf(self.filter()) !== -1;
    });
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(locations));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- The text field triggers the filtering with the textInput binding -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter locations" data-bind="textInput: filter">
<!-- The list iterates through the computed observable -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredLocations">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

以下でいかがでしょうか。`ko.utils.arrayFilter` では第1引数に配列を指定します。

```js
// Model
var locations = [
  { name: 'My House' },
  { name: 'Bakery' },
  { name: 'Restaurant' },
  { name: 'Supermarket' },
  { name: 'Pub' }
];

// ViewModel
var ViewModel = function(locations) {
  var self = this;

  self.locations = locations;
  self.filter = ko.observable('');
  // filteredLocations is computed based on the filter observable
  // entered by the user
  this.filteredLocations = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations, function(location) {
      return location.name.indexOf(self.filter()) !== -1;
    });
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(locations));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- The text field triggers the filtering with the textInput binding -->
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter locations" data-bind="textInput: filter">
<!-- The list iterates through the computed observable -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredLocations">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```